# Solving for a family of orthagonal trajectories

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

Given

$y = cx^2$,

I'm asked to find the family of trajectories orthagonal to that. I begin by differentiating to get

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2cx $

Then I replace $c$ with $\frac{y}{x^2}$, so

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y}{x}$

Then I take the negative reciprocal so the the trajectories are orthogonal,
getting

$\frac{dy}{dx} _{orthagonal} = \frac{-x}{2y}$

Then I perform seperation of variables, so

$2y dy = -x dx$

and integrating

$y^2 + \frac{x^2}{2} = C$ (that C is meant to be a constant of integration, obviously, not the earlier lowercase variable)

Unfortunately, I'm told that the correct solution is

$x^2 + 2y^2 = c$,

which looks kind of similar but is clearly not the same thing.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$$y^2+\frac{x^2}2=C\implies 2y^2+x^2=2C=c$$

Comment: I think what's confusing me is the repeated use of "c" -- is there any reason to believe the final c is the same one stated in the problem (y/x^2), or is this just a case of a repeated variable name?

Comment: @SquarerootSquirrel nope all c are just constants, there may or may not be a relation between them, after all you just say 2y^2+x^2=2xconstant=new constant

Comment: The constant of integration can be varied from one situation to another. It simply refers to the fact that there are infinite solutions to each differential equation in mathematics